# A word for 'clothed' or 'decent'?

Tags: translation, words

Is there single word in Japanese used for '(fully) clothed' or 'decent'?  As in, 'OK, you can come in, I'm decent now' or 'At least one of the kids is (fully) clothed (or dressed).' Of course one can express this meaning with something like 服を着ている, but I just wondered if there is an actual adjective or noun which is an of opposite of 裸 or 裸体?

I tried a brief search of a couple online EJ dictionaries and looking for 対義語 of 裸・裸体 without a clear answer.  The most relevant thing I found is [this EJ item for decent](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/ej3/22192/m0u/decent/) which lists as entries 1 and 5:

> **1**〈服装などが〉まともな，適正な，ふさわしい（▼「非難される点がない」という意味が濃い）；身分相応の，妥当な
>
> **5** ((略式))人前に出られる［見苦しくない］服装をした.

Entry 1 words seem rather general to me--they are not typically used in the sense I am looking for, correct?  Entry 5 seems to be close in meaning for what I'm looking for, but is a long phrase.

Comment: For "Are you decent?" I think we just say like 入ってもいい？...

Comment: I'm non-native, and this would most surely be slangy at best, but "ちゃんとした" comes to mind. I think that might extend beyond being "fully clothed" to being "presentable to the outside world with regard to hair / shoes / belt / tie / jacket / etc." It's about showing respect for other people by having a decent appearance when you leave home (I think). My sense is that that's why you "ちゃんとする". As I'm non-native, definitely ask a native about "ちゃんとする".

Comment: @choco and David_W, Just in case this was unclear, I'm not asking about what types of things one can say in this situation.  I am specifically asking if there is antonym of 裸 (which one could preferably use in the example situations).  Most nouns I can think of that describe a state have antonyms (or quasi-antonyms), and I was just wondering, if you have a group of people, some of whom are clothed and some unclothed, can you describe this with antonyms in Japanese?

Comment: 「着替え終わった？入るよ」　←　アニメで聞いたような気がします

Comment: In that case how about 「服着てる？」 (この映画では冗談っぽく「裸じゃない？」って訳されてますけど　https://youtu.be/Wy5-w4RPVy8?t=43　)

Comment: Both English and Japanese verbs can modify nouns. You expressed your thought with "clothed" and "dressed", which are verbs. So, the purest translation is to choose a Japanese verb meaning "clothed", and then use it as an adjective (because that is how you expressed yourself in English).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「[身なり](http://bit.ly/1JPkKyK)」 is a noun meaning "clothed appearance." English phrases like "dress neatly" or "tidy oneself up" can be translated as

> 「[身]{み}なりを[整]{ととの}える」

in Japanese.

"OK, you can come in, I'm decent now." could be said

> 「はい、[入]{はい}っていいですよ。[身]{み}なりが[整]{ととの}いましたから。」
>
> or
>
> 「オーケー、入っていいよ。身なり整ったから。」

However, 「身なりを整える」 sounds somewhat formal. So, the example expressions which other users have suggested in the comments are more common in casual conversations.

In [浴衣]{ゆかた} and [着物]{きもの} dress worlds, 「[着姿]{きすがた}」 is a noun meaning "dressed appearance."  But this word seems not to fit your context.

Sometimes, [着衣]{ちゃくい} is used as an antonym of 裸 in some contexts, although the official antonym of [着衣](http://bit.ly/1UAhTV1) is [脱衣](http://bit.ly/1NhenZI). In the porn world, 着衣 seems to be an antonym of [全裸](http://bit.ly/1UAicPn). However, 着衣 itself is a formal word. "Fully-clothed swimming" is called [着衣水泳](http://bit.ly/1g8AzIn) or 着衣泳 in Japanese. Anyway, 着衣 may be too formal to fit your context, but it's a possible word in some situations.

In colloquial Japanese, many people use 「[見]{み}せられる[格好]{かっこう}」 to express a clothed appearance. For example,

> (knock, knock)
>
> Clothed [涼太]{りょうた}「[美咲]{みさき}ちゃん、[迎]{むか}えに[来]{き}たよ。ドア[開]{あ}けて。」
>
> Half-naked [美咲]{みさき}「あ〜〜まだ、[見]{み}せられる[格好]{かっこう}してない。ちょっと[待]{ま}って。」
>
> Clothed 涼太「いいよ、[俺]{おれ}、そーゆーの[気]{き}にしないから。[開]{あ}けて。」
>
> Half-naked 美咲「わたし、[気]{き}にするから。もうちょっとだけ[待]{ま}って。」

「[人様]{ひとさま}に[見]{み}せられる[格好]{かっこう}ではない」 is a common phrase of 見せられる格好. Tweets on Twitter may not be good examples of it, but, people use this phrase like these: [tweets containing 見せられる格好](http://bit.ly/1g7f4aW).

「見せられ**ない**格好」 can mean not only [裸]{はだか}, but also various embarrassing appearances. So, 見せられ**る**格好 is not a perfect opposite of 裸. But the expression 見せられる格好 may be useful in some situations in real life.

---

#### Clothed / Unclothed Group of People

I think that there are many words which can be antonyms or quasi-antonyms of 「裸の[人々]{ひとびと}」 in various contexts.

When a noun is used to describe a group of clothed people, what kind of clothes the people wear is usually specified in Japanese. For example,

> [普段着]{ふだんぎ}の人々／ [正装]{せいそう}の人々 ／ [制服]{せいふく}の人々 ／
>
> [和服]{わふく}の人々 ／ [洋服]{ようふく}の人々 ／
>
> [厚着]{あつぎ}の人々 ／ [薄着]{うすぎ}の人々 ／ [半袖]{はんそで}の人々 ／ [青]{あお}い[服]{ふく}の人々 etc.

---

Hope that helps.